# Prisma update many, filter when set an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, prisma

I have this code, Product model & Pos model are many-to-many related:

```js
export async function updateProductRecordsWhenPosIsDeleted(
  posId: string,
): Promise<void> {
  const affectedProductsRecords: Product[] = await prisma.product.findMany({
    where: { posIds: { has: posId } }
  })

  for (const productRecord of affectedProductsRecords) {
    await prisma.product.update({
      where: { id: productRecord.id },
      data: {
        posIds: {
          set: productRecord.posIds.filter((id) => id !== posId),
        },
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Note that I need to update posIds array, filtering and removing a deleted pos.

It's possible to improve this using updateMany() method?. I'm trying this, how to access previous data? Thanks in advance.

```js
export async function updateProductRecordsWhenPosIsDeleted(
  posId: string,
): Promise<void> {
  await prisma.product.updateMany({
    where: { posIds: { has: posId } },
    data: {
      posIds: {
        set: [], // (prev) => {}  <-- How to access previous data?
      },
    },
  })
}
```